# Makefile running command with whoami

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi

I am trying to use a makefile to setup my machine. I am trying to setup FZF and have the following code. However, it seems to be replacing that command with empty space instead of the user I am logged as. I have SSH'd into the Pi, so not sure if that is the cause or if it's something else.

```
linuxfxf:
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/opt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a special character for make: it introduces a make variable.  If you want to run a recipe and have the shell see the `$` you have to escape it:

```
linuxfxf:
        sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/opt
        sudo chown -R $$(whoami) /usr/local/opt
```

Or you could use the old-school syntax `whoami` instead.